# How to bind to DatagridView Tooltip instead of Textbox?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I want to make the tooltip for one of the columns use the text from obj.sometext instead of adding new column for obj.sometext.

```
  dataGridView.DataSource= List<obj>;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `CellFormating` event of the `DataGridView` to set the tooltip for a cell.
In your custom object mark the "tooltip" property as non browsable in order to instruct the DataGridView to not generate a column for the property.

Here is a small code sample (sets the tooltip for the "Name" column):

```
public class MyObject
{
    private string _name;
    private int _age;
    private string _tooltip;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }

    [Browsable(false)]
    public string Tooltip
    {
        get { return _tooltip; }
        set { _tooltip = value; }
    }

    public int Age
    {
        get { return _age; }
        set { _age = value; }
    }
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   List<MyObject> list = new List<MyObject>();

   list.Add(new MyObject 
            { Name = "my name", Tooltip="tooltip1", Age = 18 });
   list.Add(new MyObject 
            { Name = "just my other name", Tooltip="tooltip2", Age = 18});

   this.dataGridView1.DataSource = list;
}

private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, 
                                          DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
  if ((e.ColumnIndex == this.dataGridView1.Columns["Name"].Index) && 
       e.Value != null)
  {
    DataGridViewCell cell = 
           this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
     cell.ToolTipText = 
           ((MyObject)(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem)).Tooltip;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I suggest using the CellToolTipTextNeeded event. Adjusting the code example of Hans yields

```
public class MyObject {
    private string _name;
    private int _age;
    private string _tooltip;

    public string Name {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }

    [Browsable(false)]
    public string Tooltip {
        get { return _tooltip; }
        set { _tooltip = value; }
    }

    public int Age {
        get { return _age; }
        set { _age = value; }
    }
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   List<MyObject> list = new List<MyObject>();
   list.Add(new MyObject 
            { Name = "my name", Tooltip="tooltip1", Age = 18 });
   list.Add(new MyObject 
            { Name = "just my other name", Tooltip="tooltip2", Age = 18});                                    
   this.dataGridView1.DataSource = list;
}

private void dataGridView1_CellToolTipTextNeeded(object sender, 
  DataGridViewCellToolTipTextNeededEventArgs e)   {
  if ((e.RowIndex > -1) && (e.ColumnIndex == this.dataGridView1.Columns["Name"].Index)) {
    e.ToolTipText = 
           ((MyObject)(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem)).Tooltip;
  }
}
```